# how to call function defined in other class to sampledatasource.cs in VS12 for C#

Tags: c#

//i have created one method in other class. I want to call that method in SAMPLDATASOURCE.CS. how can i do this? i want to add that line in group1- item 2

```
String ITEM_CONTENT = String.Format("Item Content: {0}\n\n",
                    "hello.. welcome to sudoku");

var group1 = new SampleDataGroup("Group-1",
        "Group Title: 1",
        "Group Subtitle: 1",
        "Assets/main.jpg",
        "Group Description: Play Sudoku");
group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-1",
        "Item Title: About Us",
        "Item Subtitle: 1",
        "Assets/index.png",
        "Item Description: About Us",
        ITEM_CONTENT,
        group1));
group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-2",
        "Item Title: Play Game",
        "Item Subtitle: 2",
        "Assets/play.jpg",
        "Item Description: Play Game",
        ITEM_CONTENT,            
        group1));
group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-3",
        "Item Title: Thanks For Playing",
        "Item Subtitle: 3",
        "Assets/MediumGray.png",
        "Item Description:Thanks",
        ITEM_CONTENT,
        group1));
this.AllGroups.Add(group1);
```

Comment: Make other class public/internal. If that other method is static call as classname.methodname() else create object of class and call obj.methodname() in your sampledatasource.cs

Comment: What compiler error do you get when you compiled this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method in SAMPLDATASOURCE without creating an object, define the function as:

```
public SAMPLDATASOURCE
{
    public static bool SomeFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

then call it in your other class as such:

```
SAMPLDATASOURCE.SomeFunction();
```

If you want to make an instance of SAMPLDATASOURCE and then call the function, simply remove static.

```
public SAMPLDATASOURCE
{
    public bool SomeFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
SAMPLDATASOURCE dataSource = new SAMPLDATASOURCE();
dataSource.SomeFunction();
```